# Ctrl+shift+arrow in VSCode doesn't select entire word

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Windows 10, if I use *ctrl+shift+(left/right)arrow-key* to select entire words the selection stops at uppercase or underscore, which is useless.

For example, if my cursor is in the start of the word:

```
    |showName
```

Using *ctrl+shift+right* selects this:

```
    [show]Name
```

‍♂️

Any way of changing this in the settings?

Comment: Are you on a MAC?

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left` to select whole words (from the cursor).  On W10 there is no default keybinding for `cursorWordPartRightSelect` which is what you are doing.  Did you make that binding yourself - if so change to `cursorWordEndRightSelect`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake here. I'm on Windows 10 and what I'm actually trying to do it ctrl+shift+arrow. I corrected the question.